# Paypal Execute Payment failed with 405 error

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal with my laravel. It is working fine in my local host. But When I am trying to make it live in Cpanel it is giving the following error. 
`Uncaught Error: Request to post /api/execute-payment/ failed with 405 error. Correlation id: unknown`

As I understand this is due to method problem. But I am using post method everywhere. But for god knows reason it is converting into a get method which is not the case in localhost.

Route.php

```
Route::post('create-payment', 'PaymentController@createPaypalPayment')->name('createPaypalPayment');

Route::post('execute-payment', 'PaymentController@executePaypalPayment')->name('executePaypalPayment');
```

Frontend:

```
        payment: function(data, actions) {
            var id = {!! json_encode($booking->id) !!};

            // 2. Make a request to your server
            return actions.request.post('/api/create-payment', {
                booking_id: id
            })
                .then(function(res) {
                    // 3. Return res.id from the response
                    return res.id;
                });
        },
        // Execute the payment:
        // 1. Add an onAuthorize callback
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            var id = {!! json_encode($booking->id) !!};
            // 2. Make a request to your server
            // console.log('Still OKay');
            return actions.request.post('/api/execute-payment/', {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID:   data.payerID,
                booking_id: id
            })
                .then(function(res) {
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending the API request to PayPal?

You're sending a post request to your application but seems you're sending a GET request to the PayPal API itself hence the error.

Comment: As I said it is working fine in local host. But when I am uploading into live server I am facing this. This is my Controller. I think The rest is handled by the paypal itself. 
`$paymentId = $request->paymentID;
        $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $this->_api_context);
        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId($request->payerID);

        try {
            $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex;
            exit(1);
        }
    return $result;`